# Create multi-column table using TableViews in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create multi-column table using multiple `TableViews` in `iOS`. It is shown in the attached picture, that is `TableViews` are located side by side. Since TableView has all functions such as TapGesture for each cell, Scrolling, etc., I like the way I implement.

The only problem is scrolling. Since each TableView has it own scrolling,  I have problem to synchronize scrolling among each other. If not, all data in each row at different columns will not match.

How can I synchronize scrolling among TableViews, i.e.if I scroll one TableView, all TableViews should scroll together.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Multi-column table in IOS created with `UICollectionView`

Comment: UICollectionView is more like photo app. I just need a table like excel. No need images. Of course I need TapGesture for each cell.

Comment: Then create excel-like layout for collectionview. What a problem?

Comment: Why do you think that `UICollectionView` is more like photo app? A collection view can look like anything you want. Just use the appropriate layout and setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some ways to get it to work. But it will be buggy and in my opinion, the incorrect approach to the problem. For this problem, I would use a `UICollectionView`. That way, you have a single `dataSource` and much more flexibility than `UITableView`. You also don't need to be using any *hacks* to get scrolling synchronised.

Comment: UICollectionView is more like photo app. I just need a table like excel. No need images. Of course I need TapGesture for each cell.

Comment: UICollectionView is capable of displaying far more than just photos. ;)

Comment: ic let me test UICollectionView.

Comment: @batuman Remember, UICollectionView is almost identical to UITableView. It just is on steroids. Can designs and layout cells however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Divide your UITableView into the number of columns you want to show as i did in samplecode then add custom labels and provide them tag

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *ci=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ci];


    if(cell==nil)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:ci];
    }


    if (tableView == your tablename)
    {

    CGFloat widthLabelHeader = CGRectGetWidth(tablename.frame)/7; // 7 is the number of columns in table view

serialnmbrlbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:401];

    if(!serialnmbrlbl)

    {

        serialnmbrlbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        serialnmbrlbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthLabelHeader, 50);
        serialnmbrlbl.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
        serialnmbrlbl.tag = 401;
        serialnmbrlbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialHebrew-Light" size:14];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:serialnmbrlbl];
    }
    serialnmbrlbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;


    diagnosisnamelbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:402];

    if(!diagnosisnamelbl)

    {

        diagnosisnamelbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        diagnosisnamelbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthLabelHeader, 50);
        diagnosisnamelbl.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
        diagnosisnamelbl.tag = 402;
        diagnosisnamelbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialHebrew-Light" size:14];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:diagnosisnamelbl];
    }
    diagnosisnamelbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;


    dischargeamtlbl = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:403];

    if(!dischargeamtlbl)

    {

        dischargeamtlbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        dischargeamtlbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthLabelHeader, 50);
        dischargeamtlbl.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
        dischargeamtlbl.tag = 403;
        dischargeamtlbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialHebrew-Light" size:14];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:dischargeamtlbl];
    }
    dischargeamtlbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

then apply second delegate method

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
    if(tableView == hospitaltable)
    {
        UIView *sectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                                     CGRectMake(0, 0, hospitaltable.frame.size.width, 45.0)];
        sectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(83/255.f) green:(200/255.f) blue:(36/255.f) alpha:1];

        CGFloat widthLabelHeader = CGRectGetWidth(hospitaltable.frame)/7;


        UILabel *namelabel1 = (UILabel*)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:201];
        if(!namelabel1)
        {

            namelabel1 = [[UILabel alloc]init];
            namelabel1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, widthLabelHeader, 45);
            namelabel1.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
            namelabel1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialHebrew-Light" size:14];
            [sectionHeaderView addSubview:namelabel1];
        }
        namelabel1.text = @"Sr. NO.";
        namelabel1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        namelabel1.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
        namelabel1.numberOfLines = 2;

        namelabel1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(83/255.f) green:(200/255.f) blue:(36/255.f) alpha:1];


        UILabel *orderdateLbl = (UILabel*)[sectionHeaderView viewWithTag:202];
        if (!orderdateLbl) {
            orderdateLbl = [[UILabel alloc]init];
            orderdateLbl.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(namelabel1.frame), 0, widthLabelHeader, 45);
            orderdateLbl.layer.borderWidth = 0.5;
            orderdateLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialHebrew-Light" size:14];
            [sectionHeaderView addSubview:orderdateLbl];
        }
        orderdateLbl.text = @"DIAGNOSIS NAME";
        orderdateLbl.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        orderdateLbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingMiddle;
        orderdateLbl.numberOfLines = 2;

        orderdateLbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(83/255.f) green:(200/255.f) blue:(36/255.f) alpha:1];
```

apply this delegate method too..

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        return 45;
}
```

and lastly

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
  return 45;
}
```

Take the help of this code you will get the required tableView

Comment: will this help if the user wants to handle touches on different columns ?

Comment: provide tap gesture on labels

Comment: @Abhi, In scrolling, how do you keep data are in the same row? Because each TableView has its own scrolling.

Comment: This doesn't actually attempt to solve the problem. You cannot lay cells out next to each other and since your solution using one UITableView it just simply won't work for @batuman's problem. UICollectionView is the correct way to do this.